# MongoDB compound index query

Tags: mongodb

Is it possible to create a compound index for a capped collection on location field & array field? Also is this possible for non-capped collection?

This is for - db version v2.0.5

Comment: Why not just try it? And please report back.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, but the 2d (geo index) has to be the first part of the key, so there are limitations.  It won't matter if it is capped or normal, the restriction will still apply, see here for more info:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing#GeospatialIndexing-CompoundIndexes

[Geospatial Indexing with a simple key first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7986027/geospatial-indexing-with-a-simple-key-first)